# unreachable code visual studio c# do while loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, do-while

I am attempting to write code (in visual studio 2012 using c#) that will allow a user to select an account using 1,2,3 or 4. i am using a do-while loop so i can use 0 to exit (break?) or run the loop again until a valid option is selected.

The problem is, Visual studio is telling me the code `validAccount = true;` is unreachable, and won't let me test it. since this method should also return a value i have a "not all code paths return a value" error, and i am getting really confused. here is my code:

```
    static int chooseAccount() {
        bool validAccount = false;
        do {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Select an Account: \r\n 1: Savings \r\n 2: Debit \r\n 3: Credit \r\n 4: Investment");
            int inputNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //by declaring int inputNumber here we save having an extra line.
            if ((inputNumber >= 1) && (inputNumber <= 4)) {
                return inputNumber;
                validAccount = true;
            }
            else if (inputNumber == 0) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: please choose an account using 1, 2, 3, 4 or 0 to exit");
            }
        } while (!validAccount);
    }//end chooseAccount
```

Maybe I've just been staring at this for too long and can't see the simple mistake I've made. I welcome a fresh perspective or direction to where i can find a solution, should this sort of problem have already been solved. (it's kinda hard to google for something like "unreachable code" when the code has to be so specific...)

Comment: The line after the return statement `return inputNumber;` isn't going to be executed. You don't need to set validAccount because its value "disappears" off the stack when you return from the function.

Comment: since you are either returning or breaking from the loop the whole validAccount logic is redundant anyway. do{} while(true) will suffice

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick replies! squashed that problem really quick! i still have a "not all code paths return a value" error though, any insight?

Comment: Check my answer for a fix to that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line with the error comes right after a return statement. Your code would, in every single case (and the compiler knows this), exit the function on the line before it, so it will never reach the next line.

You don't need to set `validAccount` to `true` to break the loop, because the `return` statement will exit the function, and therefore automatically exit the loop.

And finally, if you set `validAccount` to true and THEN return, no other function can access `validAccount`, so why did you need to bother setting it to true?

In truth, you don't need `validAccount` at all, because with your `break` and `return` statements you already control your way in and out of the loop. This will work:

```
static int chooseAccount() {
    while(true) {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Select an Account: \r\n 1: Savings \r\n 2: Debit \r\n 3: Credit \r\n 4: Investment");
        int inputNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if ((inputNumber >= 0) && (inputNumber <= 4)) {
            return inputNumber;
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: please choose an account using 1, 2, 3, 4 or 0 to exit");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code avoids the  "not all code paths return a value" as well, but returns 0. You have to configure your code to deal with 0 being returned as well.

Comment: Before, you `break`ed out of the loop if a user entered 0, and then there was no code after your loop, and so the function would hit the ending curly brace and not return anything. A function always has to return a value when it declares a return type, so the compiler throws an error.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your program!

Answer (score 0):

Switch these two:

```
return inputNumber;
validAccount = true;
```

Comment: There's no reason to set validAccount. You can't access validAccount after the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that the `return` statement will take you out of the function immediately. Then the next `validAccount = true;` will never be executed!

Comment: Thanks, that fixed one problem! I'm still getting a "not all code paths return a value" error though and i can't run to test it.